# How to see data based on month in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to have a button on the top of the page with months. It works on first click but when I click the other months, the calendar does not render anymore. Any idea?

Please see this fiddle for the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jetdk0ay/6/

**Event code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.month', function(){
    $('#calendar').empty();
    // Render the calendar
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to re-render the calendar, you might want to use the 'gotodate' function instead. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/cz2s1uon/

Mainly:

```
var calendar;
$(document).on('click', '.month', function(){
  
  var newDate = new Date();
  var month = $(this).attr('value');
  var fixedMonth = month - 1;
  newDate.setMonth(fixedMonth);
  
  if (calendar) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', newDate)
    return
  }

  calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: newDate,
    events: []
  })
})
```

Here's the documentation on this function:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate

Comment: Nice :) Can you include the documentation for this?

Comment: I've added the documentation link. I've never used `fullCalendar` before and to be honest found the docs to be pretty sparse.

Comment: Me too. This is my first time to use this library :D